# How can I use Inkscape CLI options with Inkscape portable?

Tags: inkscape, portable-apps

[I've read](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Using_the_Command_Line#Print_out_information) that you can use various CLI options with Inkscape.

However, I haven't found a way to use those with [Inkscape Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/inkscape_portable).
When I enter in my `cmd` window, e.g.

```
InkscapePortable.exe --action-list
```

...the splash screen shows up briefly, but then it exits again. When I omit the parameter, Inkscape starts with GUI.

Does Inkscape Portable just not support CLI parameters or is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Maybe the portable apps launcher adds some arguments that conflict with yours.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to check if that is the case and/or anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Inkscape for Windows ships with two executable binaries, one for GUI use and one for CLI use. Only the CLI version (`inkscape.com`) connects with the console. They are otherwise identical.

The PortableApps launcher will only launch the GUI version. `inkscape.com` is still there and you can manually launch it but it will then not use the portable environment. For general batch commands, this shouldn’t make much of a difference.

When you use the PortableApps launcher, it will pass the arguments alright—it’s just that the Inkscape process it launches will not print to your console window. It will quickly exit all the same though.

(Do not be confused by the file extension. `inkscape.com` is a normal Windows executable, not a 16-bit DOS executable.)

Comment: That's interesting. So would you suggest that I just use the `.com` executable, or that I rename the `.com` to `.exe` to get called by the PortableApps launcher?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that didn’t occur to me. Renaming it could work.